# combine rows if consecutive index exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to combine the string in column text_info in one row only if index is consecutive. The data I have looks very similar to the below table:

| index | text_info |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | word 1 |
| NAN | NAN |
| 3.0 | word2 |
| 0.0 | word3 |
| 1.0 | word4 |
| 2.0 | word5 |
| 4.0 | word6 |

I would like to combine the text in rows 0,1 and 2 in one row to look like this:

| index | text_info |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | word 1 |
| NAN | NAN |
| 3.0 | word2 |
| 0.0 | word3, word4, word5 |
| 4.0 | word6 |

The data contains similar consecutive indexes.

I tried multiple solutions including the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68200424/combine-consecutive-rows-for-given-index-values-in-pandas-dataframe) but it did not work. I also tried `multi = df.groupby('index',dropna=False)["text_info"].sum()` but it combined all the indexes in consecutive order.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. `pd.to_numeric()` is used in case your `NAN` values are strings and not `np.NaN` values.

```
(df.astype(str)
 .groupby(pd.to_numeric(df['index'],errors='coerce').diff().ne(1).cumsum(),as_index=False)
    .agg({'index':'first','text_info':', '.join}))
```

Output:

```
  index            text_info
0   0.0               word 1
1   nan                  nan
2   3.0                word2
3   0.0  word3, word4, word5
4   4.0                word6
```